# %s formatting precedes + operator in joining two strings before formatting

Tags: python, string-formatting, python-2.x

Revived some old code and tried to refactor it to match Python7 and 3 standards.

A lot of string operations used the `"Something was %s in here" % "merged"` syntax.

So I began the process of swapping this out for `.format("merged")`, worked great until this row popped up:

```
cmd = 'cat %s[0-9] | compress.sh - | ' % filename[:-2] + cmd
```

Now I thought I looked thoroughly at this and converted it into:

```
cmd = 'cat {}[0-9] | compress.sh - | '.format(filename[:-2] + cmd)
```

Seeing as the command line was built upon further the last `|` didn't really trigger any warning signs.

However, lots of head scratching and debugging later I found out the correct conversion should be:

```
cmd = 'cat {}[0-9] | compress.sh - | {}'.format(filename[:-2], cmd)
```

I'm aware that you probably should do `"%s" % ("x",) + cmd` here, but never the less, this was the code i was left with.

I asked colleagues and friends, they all assumed the same thing: *"I guess the math operator precedes the function operator of joining the string"*.

That's obviously not the case **and I'm wondering, is there a reason why `"%s" % "x"` goes before `+ "y"`**?
Technically speaking to me the *addition* operation (purely speaking math wise here) should go before any function call?

Why does Python2 treat the addition as a second hand operation to the function of merging into a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `%` string formatting operator shares precedence with the `%` remainder or modulus operator, which binds more tightly than the `+` addition operator.  See all the operators in order of precedence [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: Makes total sense when you hear it out loud. The link is great btw, will come in handy for numerous of reasons. Thank you!